# The hash table collision and increase in size

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a hashmap and around 12 element in it, at the same index, now if one more element is inserted at the same index, since now it has reached the threshold it will add the element and increase the hashmap size to double. similarly if 12 more element are added at same index then again it will resize and size will be doubled.This will lead to waste of space (other index elements will be empty).
Any lead/help will be appericiated.

Comment: Do you mean that all the elements of your `HashMap` are mapped to the same bucket? This means you should probably change your `hashCode` implementation.

Comment: yes even if the hashcode comes same the equals method should do the needful. I understand the hashcode implementation be such that it should try to produce unique integers as much possible from [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html). but in my case i am trying use the legacy code.

Comment: If the `hashCode` returns the same value for all elements, and you can't change it, it's pointless to use a `HashMap`. Use a `List`.

Comment: *FYI:* `HashMap` doesn't resize because a bucket has too many elements. Resizing is done because the total size of the map has reached a threshold, regardless of how uniform or skewed the elements are distributed into buckets.

Comment: it is returning same hashcode for say 'Hello' and 'hello', for different element hashcode will be different.

Comment: @Andreas thanks for pointing out, other empty indexes will be of no use and may cause performance issues due to more space taken?

Comment: *Performance* issue is because a **bucket** has too many key objects with the same hashcode, so the system has to do sequential search of that bucket, not because other buckets are empty. --- If you want to make any improvements, improve the hashcode of the key objects. It's the only thing that'll have any performance impact.

Comment: i agree, but if all the elements are stored at same index ,all other buckets will be empty

Comment: for the down votes in this question, i did not find any elaborate details in any of the sites or api docs.

Comment: Are you really dealing with 10s of elements? If so, it's very unlikely that there is any noticeable consequence of the wasted space _or_ of the fact that you're using HashMap differently from how it's intended. I can only imagine that really being an issue if you have thousands of elements. If that's the case, maybe update your question to describe the problem more clearly. Either way, have you done any profiling to actually determine that this is a problem?

Comment: the intention of this post is to get a clear understanding on how hashmap will optimize when collision occurs at same index and the limit increases the threshhold . As it may not have impact for smaller number of element if stored but if more elements come then it can cause some issue

Comment: also before grading the question , try to read the comments for what is expected from the post

Answer (score 0):

Like separate chaining, open addressing is a method for handling collisions. In Open Addressing, all elements are stored in the hash table itself. So at any point, the size of the table must be greater than or equal to the total number of keys.

Open addressing has several advantages over chaining:

- Open addressing provides better cache performance as everything is stored in the same table.
- A slot can be used even if the input doesn’t map to it.

You can refer to [Hashing overview](https://www.cse.cuhk.edu.hk/irwin.king/_media/teaching/csc2100b/tu6.pdf) for more details.

Comment: thanks for the comment,here  i am looking for the ways the bucket size can be reduced and the space complexity can be minimized